# Display all images in a given directory without using NODEJS ASP NET CORE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

Let's say that there is a path to a folder with only images, it can be all kinds of types (jpg, png, etc..). I want to loop through all the images in that folder and display them. I know that there are some ways to do that using NodeJS but when I tried to use that code that includes NodeJS it gave an error.

Here's an example of the code when I used NodeJS

### Code

```
<script>
    var fs = require('fs');
    var files = fs.readdirSync('~/Files/_@Data.path'); //@_Data.path represents a given path form the database.

    for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = files[i];
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
```

### Error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

My goal is to display all of the images from a given directory using only pure JS (Because I can't use anything else in the code).

Here's an example of how it should look,

### Example:

```
<script>
    /*
     A code that will give me access to the files inside the folder.
    */

    for(let i = 0; i < /*the variable where it all be stored*/.length; i++){
        /*
         Code that will display the images 
        */
    }
</script>
```

Any way of displaying the images will be accepted, but preferably, pure js will be great.

Comment: client-side you can't do this... you'd be outside of the browser sandbox.  For server-side,  you could have the controller return the values to a callback.  Is this folder on the client-side or server-side?

Comment: The folder is on the server side

Comment: I give the data in a Model which contains some data and the path to the folder where the image is

Comment: Why is this tagged with ASP.NET Core if you're using Node.js?

Comment: My project is ASP.NET in VS2019, I've tried to find a way to do that without NodeJS but I couldn't. I need to find a way to display those images with or without NodeJS

Comment: `img.src = files[i];` <-- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: you can iterate based on the data/results given from the controller.  The model(s) returned would have the path(s).

Comment: You can do this in JS or in standard ASP.NET type code.  I would suggest that you store each file's path along with your model.  Blindly outputting all file paths in a directory seems a little unsafe.  I'd create a table for image paths along with date uploaded, last modified and anything else you'd need... maybe a user-id, ip, etc... You can iterate at the .cshtml file. (view)  You could also do that via javascript in a callback... it depends on your current site's architecture.  (Single page application?)  Be careful with user-submitted content if that's what this is.